# Firebase cannot set or update or push when has "-" on path ?? failed: permission_denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script

I'm facing a error from firebase ; I got error
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: update at /Workorder/66/6601-001/Tag/T01 failed: ***permission_denied***

When Path has "-" on it  , but after remove - or change to other string , fb can be updated perfectly

```
     window.printDone=(TagArray)=>{
       TagArray[0] = "6601-001T01" 

// if  "6601-001T01" got permision denied
// if  "6601A001T01" can be updated
// FYI firebase rule .read , .write = true 
    
      var Year = TagArray[0].slice(0,2);
      var WO = TagArray[0].slice(0,8); 
      var TagID = TagArray[0].slice(8,11);
      var obj = {}
                            obj.Print =  "DONE"
                                    
                      update(child(dbref,"Workorder/"+Year+"/"+ WO +"/Tag/"+TagID),obj)
    
    }
```

Any suggestion ??